# Woocommerce хуки корзины

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте. Нужен подходящий хук для добавления акционного товара в корзину покупателя.
Идея такова - если в корзине сумма больше чем, например, 100 условных единиц, то мы добавляем акционный товар в корзину.

```
   function add_free_product_to_cart(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $product_id = 2006; 
    $found = false;
    if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) 
    {
        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) 
        {
            $_product = $values['data'];
            if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
            $found = true;
        }
        if(!$found)
        {
            $maximum = 100;
            $current = WC()->cart->subtotal;
            if($current > $maximum){
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
            }

        }

    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_free_product_to_cart' );
```

но при хуке на "добавления в корзину" неудобно, так как сумма в корзине может быть 90 условных единиц и при добавлении нового товара например в цену 20 единиц, хук не сработает, а в корзине уже будет 110 единиц , и там уже должен будет быть наш акционный товар.

Может есть хук при "переходе в корзину" или при "оформлении корзины"??
Благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хуков много, можно попробовать такой: woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review.

Полный перечень: [Официальная документация WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)